# Fixed positioning an ad in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css

**Can skip to the edit for a more up to date explanation.**

I can't seem to set an ad that gets written out via `document.write()` to a fixed position. It works fine in all other browsers besides IE, and that includes IE9.

Here is an example: http://htinteractive.com/bottom_bar/demo.html

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. I'm running out of ideas.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I've narrowed the problem down to the following IE issue I'm having.  To simplify it down...

```
<style type="text/css">
    #temp1
    {
        position:fixed; 
        bottom:0; 
        height:100px; 
        width:100px; 
        border:solid 2px red;
    }
</style>

<!--WORKS IN IE-->
<div id="temp1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\">\nif(typeof(cachebuster) == \"undefined\"){var cachebuster = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000)}\nif(typeof(dcopt) == \"undefined\"){var dcopt = \"dcopt=ist;\"} else {var dcopt = \"\"}\nif(typeof(tile) == \"undefined\"){var tile = 1} else {tile++}\ndocument.write('<scr'+'ipt src=\"http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/shz.bloomington/home;pos=728x90_1;' + dcopt + ';tile=' + tile + ';sz=728x90;ord=' + cachebuster + '?\"></scr'+'ipt>');\n</scr" + "ipt>");
    </script>
</div>


<!--FAILS TO FIX POSITION IN IE-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="temp1">');
    document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\">\nif(typeof(cachebuster) == \"undefined\"){var cachebuster = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000)}\nif(typeof(dcopt) == \"undefined\"){var dcopt = \"dcopt=ist;\"} else {var dcopt = \"\"}\nif(typeof(tile) == \"undefined\"){var tile = 1} else {tile++}\ndocument.write('<scr'+'ipt src=\"http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/shz.bloomington/home;pos=728x90_1;' + dcopt + ';tile=' + tile + ';sz=728x90;ord=' + cachebuster + '?\"></scr'+'ipt>');\n</scr" + "ipt>");
    document.write('</div>')
</script>
```

Anyways, I really need the **2nd method** to work, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how.

Thanks.

Comment: IE before IE9 does not support `position: fixed` at all.  You have to fake it with a JavaScript solution.

Comment: That's odd... it's working fine all the way down to IE 7 for me...? My real issue though seems with an object being written via document.write into an element that has fixed positioning.

Comment: Really??  Well I could be wrong of course, though I'm almost certain it doesn't (didn't) work in IE6.  I'll try 7 in a sec because it'd sure be neat if it does work :-)

Comment: IE6 indeed does break everything, I personally don't care about it anymore and just slap on one of these bad boys... http://www.ie6nomore.com/

Comment: `position:fixed` works in IE7 and up. However the original question didn't specify which version he was having problems with.

Comment: I'm having problem with all IE versions. I thought I made that clear with "Works fine in all other browsers besides IE, and that includes IE9." The issue isn't just fixed positioning, it's an ad that's written out via document.write into an element that has fixed positioning.

Comment: Are you running IE in compatibility mode?

Comment: I don't think so... I have it on whatever the default setting is... the fact that the issue seems to also be the same no IE7, which I'm not sure if it has compatibility mode leads me to believe this doesn't really matter.

Comment: To further elaborate on the compatibility mode question, it's grayed out so I can't even select it from the Tools menu, if this means it's already in compatibility mode, how do I unselected it?

Comment: According to your demo page you seem to have figured out the problem. I looked at it in IE8 and it works fine for me.

Comment: please check if you are using proper doc type. sometimes it will cause quirks mode in ie if doc type is inappropriate.

Comment: @jimmykup that's odd... it doesn't do the same for me...  the bar gets fixed position, but the ad inside of it appears at the top... would you mind sending me the exact IE version 8.xxx you are using?

Comment: @woodykiddy yep I am, I've even tried a few different ones just to make sure

Comment: @Pointy position:fixed works in IE>=7 with these three doctypes that I know of:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: @Matt OK Thanks!  Oddly enough I don't think I've personally ever found a use for it; maybe once or twice over the past several years :-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe IE needs the `temp1` DIV to be ended before writing the script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="temp1"><' + '/div>');
    document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\">\nif(typeof(cachebuster) == \"undefined\"){var cachebuster = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000)}\nif(typeof(dcopt) == \"undefined\"){var dcopt = \"dcopt=ist;\"} else {var dcopt = \"\"}\nif(typeof(tile) == \"undefined\"){var tile = 1} else {tile++}\ndocument.write('<scr'+'ipt src=\"http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/shz.bloomington/home;pos=728x90_1;' + dcopt + ';tile=' + tile + ';sz=728x90;ord=' + cachebuster + '?\"></scr'+'ipt>');\n</scr" + "ipt>");
</script>
```

**EDIT** (in response to your comment):

Since you want the ad script to go inside the div, you will have to put `document.write` aside and create the script programmatically, so you can simply call `appendChild` to put it into the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="temp1"><' + '/div>');
    if(typeof(cachebuster) == "undefined") {
        var cachebuster = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000);
    }
    if(typeof(dcopt) == "undefined") {
        var dcopt = "dcopt=ist;";
    } else {
        var dcopt = "";
    }
    if(typeof(tile) == "undefined") {
        var tile = 1;
    } else {
        tile++;
    }    
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/shz.bloomington/home;pos=728x90_1;"
        + dcopt 
        + ";tile=" + tile
        + ";sz=728x90;ord=" + cachebuster + "?";
    divTemp.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Please note that I cannot be 100% sure I did not make some typo while reformatting the script, with all those escaped sequences...

Comment: This is the behavior it seems to exhibit by default. Even though I wish it wouldn't. I want that script to be written out inside that temp1 div.

Comment: if you use appendChild you can't use document.write anymore.. and ads usually use that a lot

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but seems like it should work:

```
<script>
(function(){
  var w = window,
    d = document,
    s = d.createElement('script'),
    div = d.createElement('div'),
    el = [].slice.call(d.getElementsByTagName('script'), -1),
    baseUrl = 'http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/shz.bloomington/home;pos=728x90_1;';
  // end var block

  if(!("cachebuster" in w)){
    cachebuster = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000);
  }
  dcopt = "dcopt" in w ? "" : "dcopt=ist;";
  tile = "tile" in w ? tile+1 : 1;

  div.id = 'temp1';
  div.appendChild(s);
  el.parentNode.inserBefore(div, el);
  s.src = baseUrl + dcopt + ';tile=' + tile + ';sz=728x90;ord=' + cachebuster + '?';

})();
</script>
```

Comment: hmmm... trying this out but, keep getting el.parentNode is undefined... wrapped it in a few divs just in case, but same issue

Comment: fixed that issue via... el = document.getElementById('random'),   but the main issue of not positioning the fixed element still exists...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the script tags are not embedding the ad inside your DIV as you would expect. 
According to IE Developer tools, the ad is outside of your DIV and therefore doesn't get the positioning.

Using your example code changing #temp1 to just an A positions your ad where you want it.

The problem is just that your ad is not receiving the style. If you have the option of getting your ad to come back with an ID then you could probably base your style on that or alternatively use DOM manipulation to get your ad in the right spot.

The deeper issue, getting the ad script to render its content inside your DIV I'm just not sure about.

Update:

I believe the difference to IE is the method of using the SCRIPT tag. Using the src attribute to load script from another location seems to break the node tree.

Here's some evidence:

http://jsfiddle.net/wuqVw/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/wuqVw/2/

In the first example you can see that the ad is inside of the DIV whereas in the second it is below. There is probably some rule in IE that says SCRIPT tags with src attributes belong in the HEAD so it's putting them outside your DIV.

Answer (score 1):

check to see if your HTML has DTD format

Answer (score 1):

This resource might help

http://ryanfait.com/resources/fixed-positioning-in-internet-explorer/

You can also use browser specific [hacks](http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/) or you can specify a different document:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
```

Answer (score 1):

When writing script with an "src" attribute, some browsers parse the following inline code before actually running the external script. The result of the external script will be written outside of the div, because the inline code creates it, this was true for a lot of browsers a while back.

There's no simple way to overcome this, either put the div in the html, or in the external script.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you put following on top of your page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
```